# Chinese character doesn't support bold in pdf of jasper report?

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

I have using jasper report to export as pdf. in that report the english character support bold, but the Chinese character not support.

i have use this configuration.

```
  pdf font: STSong-Light
  Pdf embedded: true
  pdf encoding: uniGB-UCS2-H
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add iTextAsian.jar as part of the java library.
Can include the jar file in Option -> Classpath.
*Remember to restart iReport